# ssh error because pub key not present

Tags: ssh, key-authentication

I have a .ssh directory with a lot of keys to a lot of systems, using a collection of ssh config files, this has worked flawlessly for a few years now.

I reinstalled my machine yesterday (from Ubuntu 20.10, to Ubuntu 20.10),and started getting an error saying

`pubkey "/home/michael/.ssh/vendor.key": invalid format`

doing an strace showed

`openat(AT_FDCWD, "/home/michael/.ssh/vendor.key.pub", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)`

This file has never existed, and I've never seen this error before in the ~4 years that it has been in use.

In addition to this, we also have CI/CD processes that failing because of this error. This process has been running error free for a few months now, but yesterday started getting this error. (this runs openjdk:8-jdk, with openssh-client installed)

What has caused this error to suddenly start? and is there an easy way to fix this? (Ideally that doesn't involve creating all of the associated public keys - my ssh directory is large, and a little too haphazard to script easily)

Comment: If your reinstallation was also a major OS version upgrade, the key might have been created using old SSH protocol version 1.x key formats. The old protocol has been proven to have fundamental flaws and so modern SSH versions are deprecating the support for the old protocol version and the associated key formats. Also, the strace indicates the command is looking for "vendor.key.pub" that does not seem to be there.

Comment: @telcoM it was u20.10 to u20.10 (multipass died, after an hour of kicking it I got bored and reinstalled) the .ssh directory lives in a /home directory disk, so it remounted that and all was as before. I know it is looking for the key.pub, my question is that I've never had that error before.

Comment: @roaima apologies - ubuntu 20.10 - the CI/CD process runs docker image openjdk:8-jdk (which I believe is buster based) with openssh-client installed

Comment: No worries. Does your `vendor.key` start with `-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----` or some other informational marker? Or does it have a single line in the shape `ssh-rsa AAABC...long...string..of...characters...`, optionally followed by a comment other identifier?

Comment: the keys are fine, the error comes purely from the missing public key file. last week the private key would connect as expected. Now it requires the public key to be there too. As much as anything this is to save the next person who happens across this problem some time. But also because I'd like to understand what happened between last week and today @roaima

Comment: Can you post the output of `ssh -vvv` for both cases (when the public key and there and when it is not)? A diff of the two outputs might surface something.

Comment: Does `touch /home/michael/.ssh/vendor.key.pub` change the error at all?

Comment: @roaima an empty file doesn't make any difference

Comment: @MikeV the only difference between the two ssh -vvv outputs is that the pubkey is sent as part of the auth. The error is thrown immediately after the connection though

Comment: Have you lost your ~/.ssh/config file somewhere in the upgrade? Maybe (just a guess) it defined somewhere else to look for the public key? Other than that I'm out of ideas right now

Comment: yeah its a weird one! @roaima - it is a located in a home directory on a separate disk that was remounted. I posted this with the thought that someone would say 'ahh yes that's because of x thing' - but it seems its something weird